# Bit of majority detection in 8051 without wasting clock cycles

Tags: optimization, serial-port, uart, sampling, 8051

I'm trying to see if theres a much simpler way of doing this. What I'm doing is making four UARTs in an 8051 microcontroller in which each UART has transmission disabled and the reception for each one is sensed on ports P0.0 through P0.3 respectively through photo-transistors (think wireless here).

In order to make this thing reliable I feel I need to sample the port several times in order to get correct data. I believe in an 8051 setup, if I use its hardware UART, it automatically samples the bit at 16x or 32x the baud rate.

My code below does an OK job at sampling the data but the problem is that it is slow, and somehow I think there may be a faster way to sample the data with boolean operators of some sort?

This is my code:

```
SAMPLE equ P0   ;port to sample incoming data
MAJ equ 40h     ;Where to store majority counts
MAJT equ 20h    ;Majority track byte. Were interested in MSB
SCANRATE equ 4h ;# times to scan data before processing it

timer_interrupt:
    mov A,SAMPLE      ;get sample of data
    mov R1,#MAJ
    next: 
        rrc A         ;get one bit of sampled data
        jnc noincmaj
          inc @R1     ;add 1 to that specific bit counter if bit=1
        noincmaj:
        jc incmaj
          dec @R1     ;subtract 1 from that specific bit counter if bit=0
        incmaj:
        inc R1        ;use next bit counter#
    cjne R1,#MAJ+4h,next 
    ;loop ends when desired bit counter# is 5 (we only sample 4 bits)

    djnz R7,noprocess
      mov R0,#MAJ+3 ;Start at end of data since MSB feeds into value 1st
      nextbit:
        mov MAJT,@R0    ;Get count of bit counter
        mov @R0,#0h     ;and clear count
        mov C,MAJT.7    ;If count < 1 then bit is set otherwise its cleared
        rlc A           ;shove result into resulting byte
        dec R0          ;go to previous bit counter
      cjne R0,#MAJ-1,nextbit ;continue until all bit counters are done
      ;Accumulator has scanned value
      mov R7,#SCANRATE
    noprocess:
reti
```

This is my code template of the idea I want to achieve:

```
timer_interrupt:
        mov R6,SAMPLE      ;get sample of data
        mov A,OLDDATA
        ; some_logical_operator_here_on_R6?
        mov OLDDATA,A
        djnz R7,noprocess
          mov A,OLDDATA
          ;Accumulator has scanned value
          mov R7,#SCANRATE
        noprocess:
reti
```

So my question is, with using code that takes fewer clock cycles than the first one I posted, how do I determine after SCANRATE scans if after the majority of the scans a particular bit in a byte is set or clear?

As a concrete example, of what I'm trying to ask, if the SCANRATE is 5, and the values coming in are the following in order:

```
01010101
11111111
11110000
00001111
11001100
```

Then I want the end result (before R7 is set) to be:

```
11011101
```

So whats a simpler way to achieve this for the 8051 processor without using the first code above?

Comment: *"it automatically samples the bit at 16x or 32x the baud rate"* -- The typical UART only uses the high-rate sampling to detect the leading edge of the start bit.  Then each bit is only sampled once at its center.  Of course this scheme assumes a reliable, i.e. low latency, sample at the center of each bit.

Comment: UART over-sampling is NOT about multiple sampling or averaging, it’s about synchronising with the incoming data so the UART can sample at the centre of the bit-period.